# How to input Chinese Radicals with ibus Pinyin Intelligent Keyboard?

Tags: input-method, ibus

I am using *Pinyin Intelligent Keyboard* of `ibus` so as to enter *Traditional Chinese* characters into my documents.

However, I have discovered that the input method does not seem to allow me to type some *Chinese Radicals*. For example, [Radical number `10`](http://www.archchinese.com/traditional_chinese_radicals.html)

```
10     儿    legs    er4
```

does not show up in the list of suggested words when I type `er`.

I know that in Simplified Chinese `儿` is used as a replacement of `兒` in Traditional Chinese.

However, since `儿` is listed as a *Radical* in *Traditional Chinese* in various sources, I would expect to be able to type it even when using the *Traditional input method*.

Is there some work-around that does not involve using the *Simplified input method* in addition to the one I already use?